# Non-deterministic response to podio api call

Tags: podio

My company uses a systemd service that makes rest api calls to the podio API in a python wrapper on a services server. The process takes in bugsnag bugs, checks that a podio bug item with that external ID already exists, and then creates a new podio bug if no associated podio bug exists and updates any existing item if one does exist. Recently, this check was behaving unpredicatably. It would encounter a request for a given bugsnag ID and for no discernable reason would fail to find a podio bug with a matching external ID on one call, and then successfully find one the next call. The specific API rest call is https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747, filtering by external ID.

We haven't been able to recreate the issue on local testing, and reverting the code running on our services server to before a major refactor (the issue started happening around the same time) didn't stop the issue from happening. Was there a change in how the filter request works recently? Even so, that wouldn't explain why we are getting different responses for the same call.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if I'm handing you a Red Herring but, I had to rewrite my Podio.Net code because all the references to integer Podio ItemIds were acting erratically like you described. The issue was that Podio's Id numbering system exceeded the size of an Integer and I had to switch all the calls to Long ItemId values.